# Incorrect first element of list in C (linux/list.h)

Tags: c, list, element

Alright, guys, here goes.

I am trying to simulate basic memory management (LRU) with a list in C. I am using the implementation provided by linux/list.h, and I am having difficulty building my list initially, before the list (e.g. physical frames) fills up. I'm going to post a snippet of my code (along with output) and explain it afterwards:

```
/* Initialize list */
LIST_HEAD(listInstance);

myFrame** frameInstance;
frameInstance = (myFrame**) malloc(
        frameTableSize * sizeof(*frameInstance));
```

Later on, when I'm actually checking for a free slot:

```
/* List operations */
frameInstance[j] = (myFrame*) malloc(
        sizeof(frameInstance));
frameInstance[j]->Index1 = lv1IndexNum;
printf("Index1: %d\n", frameInstance[j]->Index1);
printf("j: %d\n", j);

/* Add most recently used frame to the head of the list */
list_add(&frameInstance[j]->list, &listInstance);
j++;

list_for_each(pos, &frameInstance[0]->list) {
    tmp = list_entry(pos, myFrame, list);
    printf("%d, ", tmp->Index1);
}
printf("\n");
```

So, listInstance is my actual list, frameInstance is an element of my list (it contains the data I actually care about, **Index1**), and j is simply a counter that will make sure that I don't overfill my list with respect to how many physical frames I have (this is not shown).

This is my output from the above code:

> Line 0: 
>   Found a free frame...
>   Index1: 1
>   j: 0
>   0,
>
> Line 1: 
>   Found a free frame...
>   Index1: 79
>   j: 1
>   0, 79,
>
> Line 2: 
>   Found a free frame...
>   Index1: 23
>   j: 2
>   0, 23, 79,

The problem here is obvious. The first element is clearly incorrect. Furthermore, list_add() is not adding frameInstance's to the head of the list, but rather to the second element of the list.

As some of you may be thinking, maybe it's just adding the elements one after the head (for example, adding the first element, of Index1: 1, would produce a list of 0, 1,), so I tried printing out an extra tail after the list, like so:

```
...
list_for_each(pos, &frameInstance[0]->list) {
    tmp = list_entry(pos, myFrame, list);
    printf("%d, ", tmp->Index1);
}
tmp = list_entry(pos->next, myFrame, list);
printf("%d, ", tmp->Index1);
```

This produced an extra 0 at the tail end of the list. So, that's not the problem.

What can you guys see about my code that is incorrect? I can provide more code, though this is already tl;dr....

Thanks

UPDATE:

So I've discovered a fairly significant fact about this list. The list, as we have been visualizing it in terms of head and tail, is backwards. For example, in a list of

> 0, 158, 15, 163, 840, 117, 632, 862,

when I remove the "tail" with

```
list_del(&frameInstance[frameTableSize - 1]->list);
```

I am actually removing the most recently accessed element (e.g., the "head"). This would result in a list like so:

> 0, 15, 163, 840, 117, 632, 862,

I hope this helps.

Comment: Pay attention to `frameInstance[j] = (myFrame*) malloc (sizeof(*frameInstance));`, you're allocating the wrong size, because `*frameInstance` is a pointer, not the actual structure.

Comment: Okay. However, this did not fix my problem. I haven't been getting any errors that seem to be related to size of memory yet.

Comment: it was just a quick comment, but you haven't fixed it. You should be using `sizeof(**frameInstance)` if you want the correct size. The size of `frameInstance` is also the size of a pointer. This will probably not solve your problem, just avoid other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem was that my and the list.h interpretation of head and tail was opposite. I assumed that you would always want O(1) access to the head, thus your least recently used item would be found at the tail. Their interpretation was the other way around.

In the end, I scrapped it all as it was murdering my brain and have decided to implement a virtual time system, which tracks the time in which each frame was referenced last. The LRU element is the one with the lowest virtual time (largest gap).